# Symfony doctrine validate unique constrain everytime

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

I have an entity with a unique constraint:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Relaciones
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="relaciones",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="persona_relacion_unica_idx", columns={"id_persona_principal", "id_persona_relacionada"}, options={"where": "(isActive IS TRUE)"})})
 */

class Relaciones
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="relaciones_id_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Personas
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Personas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_persona_principal", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $personaPrincipal;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Personas
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Personas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_persona_relacionada", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $personaRelacionada;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

}
```

and everytime I update the database it makes the same changes

```
# php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

 The following SQL statements will be executed:

     DROP INDEX persona_relacion_unica_idx;
     ALTER TABLE relaciones ALTER observacion TYPE VARCHAR(255);
     ALTER TABLE relaciones ALTER observacion DROP DEFAULT;
     CREATE UNIQUE INDEX persona_relacion_unica_idx ON relaciones (id_persona_principal, id_persona_relacionada) WHERE (isActive IS TRUE);


# php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

 Updating database schema...

     2 queries were executed


 [OK] Database schema updated successfully!                                                                             


# php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

 The following SQL statements will be executed:

     DROP INDEX persona_relacion_unica_idx;
     CREATE UNIQUE INDEX persona_relacion_unica_idx ON relaciones (id_persona_principal, id_persona_relacionada) WHERE (isActive IS TRUE);
```

Any idea?

---

UPDATE

```
# php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

Mapping
-------


 [OK] The mapping files are correct.                                                                                    


Database
--------


 [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

Comment: What do you get by `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` ? (please add info to your question as an **Update** section at the end)

Comment: Added that info

Answer (score 0):

You should update your database schema:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

this way, you will have latest changes into your database.

let me know if it could resolve the problem